# how we can display data in grid view in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I am getting following thing when I trying to get data from Sql server data base and display it in GridView. My code as follows:

```
string connstr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Aman;User ID=sa; Password=123";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
        conn.Open();
        da = null;
        string strsql = "Select File_ID,File_Name,File_Type from Upload_file";
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(strsql, conn);
        da.Fill(ds, "Upload_file");

        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Upload_file"].DefaultView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

[image]

Comment: It's not really clear what you want the output to be. Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 1):

To display data in grid view on your view do something like this (ASP.Net MVC razor):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Heading
</td>
</tr>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
<tr>
<td>
@* Something that you want to display *@
</td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want do particular operation to data retrieved you should do it in the rowdatabinding/celldatabinding event, otherwise you should define columns or in the markup or by codebehind
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
           string connstr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Aman;User ID=sa; Password=123";
           SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
           conn.Open();
           SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select File_ID,File_Name,File_Type from Upload_file ", conn);
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           adapter.Fill(dt);
           conn.Close();
           GridView1.DataSource = dt;

           GridView1.DataBind();
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way could be:

```
//Create sql DATA source by passing connection string and select command
SqlDataSource mySqlDataSource= new SqlDataSource("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Aman;User ID=sa; Password=123", "Select File_ID,File_Name,File_Type from Upload_file");

//Assign the data source to GridView data source
GridView1.DataSource = mySqlDataSource;
//Do data binding
GridView1.DataBind();
```